# Is it possible to check installed addons in firefox using a webpage (php/javascript)?

Tags: javascript, php, firefox, xul

I need to check, whether my Firefox addon is installed or not when users log into my website. If addon is not installed then users will see an alert to install the addon and if addon is already installed then there will no alert.

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28241/Detecting-a-Firefox-Extension-Using-JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct method to check if an add-on is installed or not. This question was also asked here before. Please see. [How to check with Javascript if a Firefox 3 Add-on / Extension is installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/571092/how-to-check-with-javascript-if-a-firefox-3-add-on-extension-is-installed)

If it's your own add-on then you can write some custom javascript method to try to communicate with your add-on and then display alert accordingly.

Comment: Please post comment in comment section. If you know the answer then post it in here.

Comment: if you think link in you answer ... answer the question then flag as duplicate instead ... thankyou