# Detecting programmatically whether addon installed on firefox

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I would like to know 'How can we detect whether an addon/extension is installed on Mozilla Browser from our application? If suppose someone uninstalls it directly from the browser, then how our application come to know it.
Can it be possible using php,javascript or jquery?

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct method to check if an add-on is installed or not. This question was also asked here before. Please see. How to check with [Javascript if a Firefox Add-on / Extension is installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/571092/how-to-check-with-javascript-if-a-firefox-3-add-on-extension-is-installed)

If it's your own add-on then you can write some custom javascript method to try to communicate with your add-on and then display alert accordingly.

Perhaps you can find something at [window.navigator.plugins](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.navigator.plugins)?