# Why does my test if a firefox extension is installed does not work?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon-webextensions

I have developed extensions for my web-application for Chrome and Firefox. Now I would like to check, if a user has already installed the extension. If not, a message with a download link pops up.

In order do have a common code basis, I chose an option that should work with Chrome as well as with Firefox. Unfortunately it only does on Chrome.

My Code:

//page.js

```
window.addEventListener("message", function(event){
  if(event.data && event.data.direction == "from-content-script") {
    document-getElementById("message").style = "display: none";
  }
});
```

//content-script.js

```
window.postMessage({
  direction: "from-content-script",
  message: "Message from the content script"
}, "*");
```

//manifest.jsons

```
"content_scripts": [{
   "matches": ["http://localhost:3000/*],
    "js": ["content-script.js"]
}]
```

So on Chrome it works perfectly, but on Firefox it does not. I wonder if the content script is injected correctly, because if I include an alert for test purpose it does not show up.

I am referring to this: [How to check if a Firefox WebExtension is installed or not with page JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46727370/how-to-check-if-a-firefox-webextension-is-installed-or-not-with-page-javascript?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) but I cannot get it to work with firefox.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: http:localhost:3000/* is not a valid match pattern. The two forward slashes are missing.

Comment: Oh you're right, but it is correct in my code, just a copying-mistake.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detecting programatically whether addon installed on firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34963137/detecting-programatically-whether-addon-installed-on-firefox)

Comment: Checkout https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Sharing_objects_with_page_scripts

Comment: Thanks, found a solution. Firefox seems to not be able to match localhost - on every other page it works.

Answer (score 0):

As [the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Match_patterns) note:

> The path pattern string should not include a port number. Adding a port, as in: *"http://localhost:1234/*"* causes the match pattern to be ignored.

Don't use

```js
   "matches": ["http://localhost:3000/*"],
```

but

```js
   "matches": ["http://localhost/*"],
```